# Keep a screen active for x seconds

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am working with a splash screen but am doing a network call on the splash screen so the data is ready on the home screen by the time the user gets there.

Once the network call is complete it goes to the next screen, I would like the splash screen to be open though for at least x seconds even if the network call took a couple ms because when the network call is ms then the splash screen cannot even be seen.

I know how to do the delay the splash screen for x seconds but would like the network call to be included in those x seconds as opposed to network call time + x amount seconds.

Thank you

Comment: after x seconds - if network call completed close - else continue until call completed. Something like that?

Comment: Show the loading animation till data is ready, when data is ready show the next screen. Do network call in AsyncTask. it has All necessary functions you need, such as onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(), onProgressUpdate() and doInBackground()

Comment: @Stultuske yea like that.

Comment: @EagleEye i am doing the network call with AsyncTask already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Handler in side onPostExecute() Method. When your Network call in complete, call handler, it'll wait for x seconds and then after moves to another activity.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class));
        }
    }, x);// here x is time in millisecond 1 second = 1000 millseconds

} });
```

This will surely help you.

Comment: This is what i know how to do, but i dont want the network call time lets say for arguments sake is 1sec and the splash screen time i would like is 3 seconds.

The option you gave me will make the total screen time 4 seconds as apposed to the 3 seconds i want.

I would like the network call time to be included in the 3 seconds of display time?

Hope that makes more sense

Comment: Then use couterTimer for it.